# Why i can't pass data from form textbox to form textbox inside panel VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

This is the code when calling form and showing inside panel

```
 Dim frmLubesInterface As LubesInterface = New LubesInterface
      with frmLubesInterface 
            .Text = "frmLubesInterface"
            .TopLevel = False
             Panel6.Controls.Add(frmLubesInterface)
            .StartPosition = 
            .FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
            .Show()
     end with
```

This is code passing data from form and show inside form which is inside of panel

```
 Dim Itemname as string = ""
     Itemname = txtItemNameSearch.Text
     LubesInterface.txtItem.Text = Itemname - **this part is where i pass the value of data to form textbox inside panel**
```

To summary i can't pass the value of textbox to form textbox inside the panel, but when showing it as msgbox it show the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "Global" that seems to mean something different to different people.

You could do it in one of two ways as far as I am concerned, you can either pass the values to constructor or create properties and get/set those properties.

```
            Public Class Form1

                Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
                    Dim TxtFromTxtBoxOnForm2 As String = String.Empty
                    Dim Form2 As New Form2
                    With Form2
                        TxtFromTxtBoxOnForm2 = .ItmTxt
                        .TopLevel = False
                        .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
                        Panel1.Controls.Add(Form2)
                        .Show()
                    End With
                End Sub

            End Class

            Public Class Form2

                Public Property ItmTxt As String
                    Get
                        Return TextBoxOnForm2.Text
                    End Get
                    Set(value As String)
                        TextBoxOnForm2.Text = value
                    End Set
                End Property

            End Class
```

Comment: By the way, thank you for your answer it helps! cheer.

Comment: What i mean is i declare this in module and change dim to public. ( Public frmLubesInterface As LubesInterface = New LubesInterface) and now i will call it by frmlubesinterface.textbox.text

Answer (score 0):

I already get it. i should declare global and call the form inside the panel.